# Emacs set C-RET-<key> to M-<key>

Tags: emacs

Pretty self explanatory, but I'd like for regular `RET` to be `RET`, while `C-RET` will act as `M`. I'd like to do this because I have caps lock set to `C` and pressing both pinkies would be a convenient `M`.

Thanks in advance.